# How to train SparkML gradient boosting classifer given a RDD

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-ml

Given the following rdd

```
training_rdd = rdd.select(
    # Categorical features
    col('device_os'), # 'ios', 'android'

    # Numeric features
    col('30day_click_count'), 
    col('30day_impression_count'),
    np.true_divide(col('30day_click_count'), col('30day_impression_count')).alias('30day_click_through_rate'),

    # label
    col('did_click').alias('label')
)
```

I am confused about the syntax to train a gradient boosting classifer.

I am following the this tutorial. 
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-classification-regression.html#gradient-boosted-tree-classifier

However, I am unsure about how to get my 4 feature columns into a vector. Because VectorIndexer assumes that all the features are already in one column.

Comment: the linked tutorial assumes a `DataFrame`, not an `RDD` though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `VectorAssembler` to generate the feature vector. Please note that you will have to convert your `rdd` to a `DataFrame` first.

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler
vectorizer = VectorAssembler()

vectorizer.setInputCols(["device_os",
                         "30day_click_count",
                         "30day_impression_count",
                         "30day_click_through_rate"])

vectorizer.setOutputCol("features")
```

And consequently, you will need to put `vectorizer` as the first stage into the `Pipeline`:

```
pipeline = Pipeline([vectorizer, ...])
```

Comment: If I convert my RDD to a dataaframe, does it mean that it has to be evaluated? My dataset is too big to fit in memory

Comment: A Spark DataFrame is still a distributed dataset. You can do this by `rdd.toDF()`.